# Declare variable for different classes

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I'm using SCSS and I have a variable `$arial: 'Arial', serif;`

Now I want to do something like that:

```
.english{
    $arial: 'Arial', serif;
    font-family: $arial;
}
.japan{
    $arial: 'Noto Sans';
    font-family: $arial;
}
```

Because from the beginning, my customer wants to display `$arial` as 'Arial', but now they're separating it to 2 pages, (English page and Japanese page).

Comment: can u plz explain clearly?

Comment: I edited my idea to make it clearer

Comment: ohh, so u have a same variable and different font. but it will work automatically depends on language select? Is this u want?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want

Comment: In which platform u are working?

Comment: Have a look at CSS variables for this. Then you could do `body { --arial: 'Arial'; font-family: var( --arial, Arial ) } body.japan { --arial: 'Noto Sans'; } `. You can change it on the fly by using CSS variables in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a newer CSS feature called CSS variables to accomplish this. Simple define what variables need to change in what context, and then import them in the definitions themselves. You can find the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Here is an example (using very easily distinguishable fonts):

```js
document.querySelector( 'h1' ).addEventListener( 'click', e => document.body.classList.toggle( 'japanese' ) )
```

```css
body {
   
  --font: 'Comic Sans MS', monospace;
  
  font-family: var(--font, cursive);
    
}

body.japanese {

  --font: 'Impact';
  
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h1>
```

With a simple class toggle, the variable is updated and the definition only needs to be made once.

Comment: Sorry this is not what I want, because I don't use `$arial` (or `--font: 'Impact'`) for the whole `body`, I just use it for a couple of classes (which is children class of `.japanese`)

Comment: @luuhoangbac This is just an example of how to use these variables, you can apply them wherever you want in your code. Just change the selector and variable names to whatever you want. The — nitation is just CSS’ way of declaring variables instead of using SASS’ $ notation.

Comment: @LuuHoangBac No shit, what does work in IE? Move on already. This is by far the most aggravating comment a web developer can read - even Microsoft dislikes IE at this point. This feature is now available on all common browsers that arent released in 2001.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make use of CSS Vars as above. To accomplish this in sassy way you can make use of sass map

```
$map:("english":"'Arial',serif","japan":"'Nato Sans'");

@each $key , $value in $map{
  .#{$key}{
    font-family:unquote($value);
  }
}
```

output

```
.english {
  font-family: 'Arial',serif;
}

.japan {
  font-family: 'Nato Sans';
}
```

Comment: Sorry this is not what I want, because I don't use `$arial` for the whole `body` (or just some classes), I want to use it for every classes which are children class of `.japanese` and have `font-family: $arial` in this class